# Infinite Scrolling in Asp.Net MVC with jQuery / AJAX Issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have got Infinite Scrolling within my ASP.Net (MVC) app mostly working albeit with some slightly strange behaviour at times.

The issue I am having is that it seems to load in the same batch of items more than once as I scroll - yet if I put a breakpoint in my controller code and slow it all down it works fine! Even if I put an alert in my jQuery code that seems OK too - it's like I am scrolling over the trigger point multiple times and it's calling the ListMore action too many times - that's all I can think anyway as I say if I put a break point into my controller that slows it down enough and I don't see it firing multiple times!

I put some debug counters in my partial view so I can see it loading page 2 multiple times for example.

I created a partial view / new controller method to retrieve page 2 and onwards data (page 1 is loaded via the main view controller method)

```
public PartialViewResult ListMore(int id = 0, int page = 1, int sort = 0)
{
    int pageSize = AppConstants.PageSize;

    // get the products for this category
    var prods = mgr.GetProducts(id, sort);

    CategoryViewModel model = new CategoryViewModel
    {
        Products = prods
        .Skip((page - 1) * pageSize)
        .Take(pageSize)
    };

    return PartialView("_ListMore", model);
}
```

The partial view is very simple :

```
@model TooledUp.WebUI.Models.Catalog.CategoryViewModel

@foreach (var item in Model.Products)
{
    <div class="col-1-3">
        @{Html.RenderPartial("_ProductGrid", item);}
    </div>
}
```

Then I have the following in my main view :

```
<div class="row clearfix">
    @foreach (var item in Model.Products)
    {
        <div class="col-1-3">
            @{Html.RenderPartial("_ProductGrid", item);}
        </div>
    }
    <div id="listmore"></div>
</div>

<div id="progress" style="display:none;">
    <img src="~/Content/images/Spinner.gif" alt="Loading" /> Loading more     products...
</div>
<div id="progressmarker"></div>
```

And my jQuery / ajax code is as follows (in the main view) - the Model.PagingInfo stuff is set one time only when the main view is invoked.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var categoryId = @Model.CurrentCategoryID;
var pageSize = @Model.PagingInfo.ItemsPerPage;
var pageIndex = 2; // already loaded page 1 - this is next to get
var sortIndex = @Model.PagingInfo.SortBy;
var pages = @Model.PagingInfo.TotalPages;

$(window).scroll(function() {
    var hT = $('#progressmarker').offset().top,
        hH = $('#progressmarker').outerHeight(),
        wH = $(window).height(),
        wS = $(this).scrollTop();
    if ((pages + 1) > pageIndex)
    {
        if (wS > (hT+hH-wH)){
            //alert(pageIndex);
            GetData();
        }
    }
});

function GetData() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/category/ListMore',
        data: {
            "id": categoryId,
            "page": pageIndex,
            "sort": sortIndex
        },
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function (data) {
            if (data != null) {
                $("#listmore").append(data);
                pageIndex++;
            }
        },
        beforeSend : function () {
            $("#progress").show();
        },
        complete : function () {
            $("#progress").hide();
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Error while retrieving data!");
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

When I have changed the position of the pageIndex++ code (because I thought it wasn't firing quickly enough before the rendering of the extra content so the same content could be loaded twice) all it did was break it the other way so that fast scrolling would enable pages (blocks) to be skipped so it would increment too quickly - jumping from page 2 to 5!

To sum up my issue is controlling that the scroll only fires once per page (block) but always fires for sequential pages.

Comment: Also check the network tab in the browser to see what's being called.

Comment: Add a flag (say `var isExecuting`) to indicate if the ajax call is executing - set it to `true` before `$.ajax({` and back to `false` in the success callback). Then in the `.scroll()` handler, only call `GetData();` if the value is `false`

Comment: Thanks seems to work well!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing based on the suggestion :

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var hT = $('#progressmarker').offset().top,
        hH = $('#progressmarker').outerHeight(),
        wH = $(window).height(),
        wS = $(window).scrollTop();
    // don't do it if we have reached last page OR we are still grabbing items
    if (pages >= pageIndex && !_incallback) {
        if (wS > (hT + hH - wH)) {
            GetData();
        }
    }
});

function GetData() {
    _incallback = true;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/category/ListMore',
        data: {
            "id": categoryId,
            "page": pageIndex,
            "sort": sortIndex
        },
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function (data) {
            if (data != null) {
                $("#listmore").append(data);
                pageIndex++;
            }
        },
        beforeSend: function () {
            $("#progress").show();
        },
        complete: function () {
            $("#progress").hide();
            _incallback = false;
        },
        error: function () {
            //alert("Error while retrieving data!");
            _incallback = false;
        }
    });
}
```

Seems to work OK now thanks for that.

Comment: where is _incallback defined?

Comment: _incallback may be a global variable.